# Finding the different rows from two resultsets based on one of the resultsets (MINUS, NOT EXISTS)

Tags: oracle, join, oracle-11g, if-not-exists

I'm testing queries on two resultsets that have the same value in certain columns on Oracle 11g. I want to exclude the rows that share these columns from my final result based on the first table. Say I have the following resultsets:

Table1 (Where `id` is a number)

```
| id | col_a | col_b | col_c | col_d | col_e
|  1 |   a1  |   b1  |   c1  |   d1  |  100
|  2 |   a1  |   b2  |   c2  |   d1  |  200
|  3 |   a2  |   b3  |   r1  |   s1  |  300
|  4 |   a9  |   b9  |   r9  |   s9  |  400
```

Table2 (where `id` is a letter)

```
| id | col_a | col_b | col_c | col_d | col_e
|  A |   a1  |   x1  |   c1  |   d1  |  100
|  B |   a1  |   y2  |   c2  |   z1  |  200
|  C |   a1  |   b3  |   c3  |   s1  |  300
|  D |   a0  |   b0  |   r0  |   s0  |  400
```

My expected result would be the rows that are different from the columns I am trying to evaluate based on Table1. Evaluating that if `col_a` and `col_c` and `col_e` are the same, remove them from my resultset. Preferrably something like this:

TableR1

```
| id | col_a | col_b | col_c | col_d | col_e 
|  3 |   a2  |   b3  |   r1  |   s1  |  300
|  4 |   a9  |   b9  |   r9  |   s9  |  400
```

Since I only really care about `col_a`, `col_c` and `col_e`, this is valid too:

TableR2

```
| col_a | col_c | col_e 
|   a2  |   r1  |  300
|   a9  |   r9  |  400
```

I would like to know if I can use, in Oracle 11g:

- `MINUS`
- `NOT EXISTS`
- Something else that I'm overlooking (Like `JOIN`s)

I've tried with the first two by doing something like this which gives me something like TableR2:

```
SELECT  col_a,
        col_c,
        col_e
FROM    Table1

MINUS

SELECT  col_a,
        col_c,
        col_e
FROM    Table2
```

And something like this which gives me something like TableR1:

```
SELECT id, col_a, col_b, col_c, col_d, col_e FROM
Table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM
    Table2
    WHERE Table1.col_a = Table2.col_a
    AND Table1.col_c = Table2.col_c
    AND Table1.col_e = Table2.col_e)
```

**Which is the best approach, in accuracy and speed, for finding the rows that are different using those criteria using Table1 as a base?**

I think using `MINUS` would give me the expected results (albeit with less data than what I'd optimally like to look at) but I've seen the `NOT EXISTS` approach being used and I'm not sure if I could use something similar so I can look at the remaining columns.

Comment: How big are the tables? What are your indexes? How fast do you need it to be? When you say that your queries produce a result set that's "something like TableR1" what does that mean? I'd expect that query to return exactly the result set you were looking for. What does it produce?

Comment: It seems that you compare the row of table1 with id=1 to the row of table2 with id='A', the row of table1 with id=2 to the row of table2 with id='B',.... If so. then you have to mention it in your description. If not, it is unclear, how your comparison works, because for every row in table1 there is a row in table2 with different values in the relevant columns.